# Bash script with options and resizing images

Tags: bash

Alright I'm trying to create a bash script that has options for users to choose from when it comes to image resizing. The script can be edited by the user to fit their needs. But it's not working & I can't figure out why.

Here's what I've got for my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ answer != 'e' ]; do #menu
clear
echo -e '[Hello $USER] what can I do for  you?\n'
echo "  
    1   Resize jpg
    2   Resize png
    3   Resize gif
    4   Resize jpeg
    5   Exit”
echo -e "\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n"
read -p  "Sir ?  " answer
case $answer in


DIR=/Yosemite/Users/Technologx/Downloads/New\ Carved\ Walls/previews/

1|rem|rm|RM|REM)
echo -e “\n.. Resizing your jpg’s!\n”
find $DIR -iname \*.jpg -exec sips -Z 150 250 {} \;
done

2|rem|rm|RM|REM)
echo -e “\n.. Resizing your png’s!\n”
find $DIR -iname \*.png -exec sips -Z 150 250 {} \;
done


3|rem|rm|RM|REM)
echo -e “\n.. Resizing your gif’s!\n”
find $DIR -iname \*.gif -exec sips -Z 150 250 {} \;
done

4|rem|rm|RM|REM)
echo -e “\n.. Resizing your jpeg’s!\n”
find $DIR -iname \*.jpeg -exec sips -Z 150 250 {} \;
done

5|rem|rm|RM|REM)
echo -e “\n.. GoodBye\n”
killall Terminal
done

echo -e “\n..Thank you for using my image resizer don’t forget to visit https://technologx.com and signup\n”

sleep 5

done
```

Comment: Define "not working" please. Also - be aware that the syntax highlighting above may very well point out your problem. Lastly, you've got Microsoft quotes in your code - I doubt they'll be doing your bash interpreter any favours :)

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: These are no double quotes: `“`

Comment: So do I need to change the quotes to ' ' because it's saying in terminal on line 4 and 42 it can't find anything for "?

Comment: Your `find` command should probably look more like `find "$DIR" -iname \*.png -exec sips -Z 150 250 {} \;`

Comment: Alright I edited the code to that but I run into this: /Users/Technologx/Documents/resizer.sh: line 36: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/Users/Technologx/Documents/resizer.sh: line 50: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You omitted the double quotes around `"$DIR"`...

Comment: `answer != 'e'`, `|rem|rm|RM|REM`, `“`, `killall Terminal`, `sleep 5`, etc. There's so much wrong in this script it might be best to start over and read a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Among all the other comments about curly quotes not being double quotes and such, this

```
while [ answer != 'e' ]; do #menu
```

can't work because it compares two unequal strings, `answer` and `e`. You should first initialize `answer` and then reference the variable as follows:

```
answer=""
while [ "$answer" != e ]; do
  ...
doneküchenrollenhalter wand
```

Next, the assignment `DIR=...` must be moved to the beginning of the script. It is misplaced following the `case $answer in` line.

Third, `case` alternatives are must be terminated by `;;`, not `done`.

Did you consider reading a tutorial or book on shell programming?

Comment: So how exactly would I go about doing it like that?